# Using a null c# model in javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, json.net

i'm trying to use my viewmodel from Razor in my script.
The problem is that sometimes, my complex Model generated by EF which have cyclic values is null.

```
var skill = @Model.Skill1 != null ? "@Model.Skill1.SkillName" : "";
```

When the @Model.Skill1 is not null, i can use @Model.Skill1.SkillName. But if @Model.Skill1 is null the result is

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

And the page is not even render.

It seem that @Model.Skill1.SkillName can't be write in the code even if the condition to access the property SkillName is not triggered.

So i tried to convert my object into a Json object but this time i have the cyclic values generating problem.

Any idea or way to bypass the problem?

Comment: Even if it worked, you're setting the string to the *string* `"@Model.Skill1.SkillName"`, not the value of `SkillName`. Are you sure that `Model` isn't null..?

Comment: Yes, i'm pretty sure of that, Model is never null but skills childs are sometimes. And I know for the "@Model.Skill1.SkillName" but if i don't, i have an error like :
    var test = C++; is not defined
C++ being my value.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're mixing languages.  If this is in your JavaScript block:

```
var skill = @Model.Skill1 != null ? "@Model.Skill1.SkillName" : "";
```

then you have *two* server-side statements there.  With no logic determining whether or not to execute them.  So they both execute, and the second one is a `NullReferenceException`.

Basically, you're trying to emit a null reference to the *client* and so the *client* can check if it's null.  But by then you've already tried to dereference it, hence the error.

Conduct the null check *server-side* and just emit the *result* to the client-side code.  Something like this:

```
var skill = '@(Model.Skill1 != null ? Model.Skill1.SkillName : "")';
```

Wrapping a value-emitting expression in parentheses in Razor `@()` means that the whole statement is server-side code and should result in a single emitted value.

Comment: good answer .. small correction though ..  if it is null .. it will become => var skill = '""' ... and if you try alert(skill) ... it will show "" on screen! ,, so i think it should be without the surrounding single quotes like this var skill = @(Model.Skill1 != null ? Model.Skill1.SkillName : "");

Comment: @AKhudairy: Quotes aren't printed when emitting a string value.  The quotes aren't actually *part of* the string, they're just the language syntax to *indicate* a string.  If you omit the client-side quotes as you suggest, that will result in a syntax error.

Comment: try this in console .. var xxx = '""'; alert(xxx); .... tell me what you get on screen! ... then try this ... var xxx = ''; alert(xxx); .. what did you get now? .... maybe my code is wrong .. i did not try to see if MVC razor engine will understand it correctly ..

Comment: @AKhudairy: You seem to be confusing the difference between client-side and server-side code.  You can't test C# in the browser console.  Test the code in the context of an ASP.NET MVC View instead.

Comment: noooo I meant try this as JS code ... anyway I think I just got what you mean .. I guess you are right .. if the Model.skill1 is null the output will actually be just nothing and not double quotes ... and the output will be var skill = ''; which is correct. my bad :)

Comment: Thank you David, A Khudairy and Rob. It work indeed like this but i though i had already try this...